# Multithreading in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

To the best of my knowledge, TensorFlow can use multithreading in two ways:

1. Perform lengthy I/O operations in separate threads
2. Execute sessions with multiple threads to reduce processing time

For #1, I used threads and queues in the past, but now the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/threading_and_queues) says I should use Datasets. Does this mean that QueueRunners and Coordinators are effectively deprecated? Are there still uses for them?

For #2, I use the session-configuration options defined in the [ConfigProto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto) message. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: "Is there anything else I can do?" So what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to use multithreading to the fullest extent possible. I'd like to know if I can do more than just setting configuration options in the session.

Comment: You can still get parallelism in datasets (see `tf.data.Dataset.shard(...)` and `tf.data.Dataset.map(..., num_parallel_calls=...)`